# Showing jscrollpanes on overflow:scroll elements

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

How can I use or modify jScrollPane to always display scroll bars on elements with overflow:scroll?  Currently jScrollPane overrides whatever overflow style is set and only renders when content exceeds the element height, but I want the behavior to more closely resemble CSS3 overflow definitions.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know from the jScrollPane site, this behavior is by design (and touted in a demo). Have you used Chrome to Inspect Element on one of the bars?  That would let you identify the HTML elements in play, and how they're being manipulated.